# Typescript: Build Object Type from Array of Objects' Property Values

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to build a generic type (Response) that will be an object containing all values from KeysForResponse, which is the values from the `valueIWant` property for each object in MyObject[]. I can't seem to figure it out, or if its even possible.  Basically, if I pass the following array into a function:

```js
[{valueIWant: 'makeMeAKey', foo: 'bar'}, {valueIWant: 'alsoMakeMeAKey', foo: 'bar'}]
```

I want to return the following type:

```js
{makeMeAkey: string, alsoMakeMeAKey: string}
```

Here is what I currently have, which isn't generic

```js
interface MyObject {
  valueIWant: string;
  nonImportantValue: string;
}

type KeysForResponse = Array<MyObject>[number]['valueIWant'];

type Response = {
  [K in KeysForResponse]: string;
};
```

Comment: Is the array known at compile-time (is static)? What is the `foo` property in the array for? How are you using the function?

Comment: The array is known at compile time.  I'm trying to make a react component reusable, which takes in a list of items to be rendered, and also takes an onSubmit callback.  I want the data thats passed into the callback to be known.  I realize that the example I used could be misleading.  I meant `string` not `foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define a generic parameter for the value of that key

```
type MyObject<T> = {
    valueIWant: T;
}

function fn <T extends string, O extends MyObject<T>> (request: O[]) : {[x in O["valueIWant"]]: string}  {
    return request.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        return {
            ...acc,
            [curr.valueIWant]: 'foo'
        }
    }, {} as {[x in O["valueIWant"]]: string})
}

const result = fn([{valueIWant: 'key1', foo: 'foo'}, {valueIWant: 'key2', foo: 'foo2'}]);
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to take the concepts you showed and apply them to my problem and sure enough, it worked.  I'll stop beating my head in to a wall for now